# Is the sound of an aux-connector DAC or CODEC?

Tags: amplifier, audio, dac, audio-codec

I am planning to take the audio aux signal of a raspberry pi and amplify it with a TPA2012D2 by Texas Instruments. In the datasheet there is a typical application circuit, which would match my needs (single ended input signal). Except I am not sure that the aux output is DAC or CODEC. Can someone explain to me if this would work?

I added a image of the typical application circuit below.

[image]

Comment: Yes the audio out from R-Pi comes from a DAC so you can just connect it as shown here.

Comment: I am curious, what a CODEC stands for?

Comment: Me too. Wasn't specified in the datasheet - searched for it.

Comment: @Marko COder DECoder.

Comment: @winny But what does it output? An analog signal? Or coded signal with some modulation?

Comment: CODEC can mean any digital code for compressing audio or video but here implies an audio method such as PCM or MP3 where the output is always analog.

Comment: [Codec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codec)

Comment: @Marko It's more generic than that. There are mp3 decode only libraries in computers as well as full encoding and decoding dito. Can't say it has an physical output rather than a stream of bits inside the software. An integrated D/A and A/D into the same IC could also be considered a CODEC, but it's a stretch.

Comment: @winny I see. The datasheet is confusing, then. It should say an audio signal, not a DAC or CODEC. By the way it think there are D-class amp IC that accepts PCM coded signal, so it wasn't clear enough what's the output of a CODEC.

Comment: @Marko Indeed. More signs to fill out the minimum count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This amp IC accepts analog audio input. You must have it. Obviously your audio output is analog. Text DAC or Codec refers to your case. If your audio is generated by computer software, it must be an output from a DAC (=digital to analog converter). Codec is more complex device, which has ADC and DAC.

The story in the datasheet warns that computer generated audio can have unhearable high frequency content which can interfere with the internal pulsed operation of the D-class amp IC. Some hearable mixing results can be generated and that's noise.

The datasheet guides to add extra RC filter to the input of the amp IC to reduce that noise. The filter attenuates the possible hf content of the audio.

Comment: While in this case it is, in actuality a CODEC's output does not have to be analog.  It may instead be some kind of pulse encoding - especially now that popular amplifiers are mostly implemented with switching rather than linear techniques, in a highly integrated system (like a phone) there may be no reason to go to analog in between, and simplicity reasons not to.